# Navbar links have wrong color gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar that adjusts to screen size which has two versions (one for large devices and one for small screens). The active links of these navbars have a color-gradient that refers to the entire graphics of the site. However, in the mobile navbar, this gradient doesn't work despite being the same class as the links in the other navbar (where it works perfectly). So here are some explanatory images:

Correctly colored link
[image: Correctly colored link]

Incorrectly colored link

[image: Incorrectly colored link]

I also attach the code of my navbar:

HTML

```
<header id="header">
        <nav id="menu">
            <a id="home" class="active large" onclick="goTo(id)">Home</a>
            <a id="presentation" class="large" onclick="goTo(id)">Chi sono</a>
            <a id="portfolio" class="large" onclick="goTo(id)">Portfolio</a>
            <a id="social" class="large" onclick="goTo(id)">Social</a>
            <a id="contactMe" class="large" onclick="goTo(id)">Contattami</a>
            <img class="iconaMenu small" src="Assets/Icons/menu.svg" alt="Menu" onclick="toggleMenu()" draggable="false">
        </nav>
        <div id="menu-small" class="hidden">
            <a id="home" onclick="goTo(id)">Home</a>
            <a id="presentation" class="active" onclick="goTo(id)">Chi sono</a>
            <a id="portfolio" onclick="goTo(id)">Portfolio</a>
            <a id="social" onclick="goTo(id)">Social</a>
            <a id="contactMe" onclick="goTo(id)">Contattami</a>
        </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
    color: var(--disabledTxtColor);
    font-size: .9rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    gap: 2rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    z-index: 3;
}

#menu-small {
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
    color: var(--disabledTxtColor);
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
    gap: 1.8rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    /* transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s; */
}

.hidden { display: none !important; }

.iconaMenu { width: 1.5rem; }

.iconaMenu:active { transform: scale(0.95); }

nav a, #menu-small a { cursor: pointer; }

nav a.active, #menu-small a.active {
    background: rgb(144,122,214);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(144,122,214) 0%, rgba(119, 143, 181) 25%, rgba(255,104,107) 50%, rgb(20, 160, 152) 75%, rgb(255, 170, 110) 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 1007px) { nav { padding-right: 1.5rem; } }
```

and Javascript

```
// gestione dei collegamenti della navbar
function goTo(daAttivare) {
  closeMenu();
  const targetSection = document.getElementById(daAttivare + "Page");
  window.scroll({
    top: targetSection.offsetTop - (4 * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize)),
  });    
}

// gestione dei link della navbar
const navSections = document.querySelectorAll("#homePage, #presentationPage, #portfolioPage, #socialPage, #contactMePage");
const navLinksLarge = document.querySelectorAll("#menu a");
const navLinksSmall = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-small a");
let currentNavSectionIndex = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  closeMenu(); // chiudi il menu per i dispositivi piccoli se è mostrato
  navSections.forEach((section, index) => {
      if (window.pageYOffset + (document.body.scrollHeight * 0.04) >= section.offsetTop) currentNavSectionIndex = index;
    });
    navLinksLarge.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.classList.toggle("active", index === currentNavSectionIndex);
    });
    navLinksSmall.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.classList.toggle("active", index === currentNavSectionIndex);
    });
});

// gestione della navbar per i dispositivi piccoli
isMenuShown = false;
menuPopup = document.getElementById("menu-small");
pageContent = document.getElementById("pageContent");
function toggleMenu() {
  isMenuShown = !isMenuShown;
  menuPopup.classList.toggle("hidden");
  pageContent.classList.toggle("contentBlur");
}
function closeMenu() {
  if (isMenuShown == true) {
    isMenuShown = false;
    menuPopup.classList.add("hidden");
    pageContent.classList.remove("contentBlur");
  }
}
function screenResize() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 450) closeMenu();
}
pageContent.addEventListener('mousedown', closeMenu, {passive: true});
pageContent.addEventListener('touchstart', closeMenu, {passive: true});
window.addEventListener("resize", screenResize, {passive: true});
```

As you know I can't attach snippets as there are eventlisteners but you can check what I said at the following link: [website](https://manux895.github.io/CiotolHouse)

Comment: I recommend checking out [mcve] as 99% of the code you provided isn't actually needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: As I said, I can't provide a snippet as it's not possible to show the problem without eventlisteners (which can't be used here). So I can't show the problem like this. I would appreciate it if you try to use the information provided which, while not perfect, is still enough to understand and possibly fix the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error was solved in a very simple way even if I don't understand the reason. Just change the css like this:

```
nav a.active, #menu-small a.active {
    max-width: max-content;
    background: rgb(144,122,214);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(144,122,214) 0%, rgba(119, 143, 181) 25%, rgba(255,104,107) 50%, rgb(20, 160, 152) 75%, rgb(255, 170, 110) 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, provide more detail. Like: Adding `max-width: max-content;` fixed this, because...

Comment: unfortunately I don't quite understand why this only happens on the second navbar. A better answer than mine would be welcome. I just noticed that with this line of code the problem is apparently fixed. I made some random attempts